# using NSTimer to move objects on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I am building a simple ios gaming app where I have to move a few objects on screen, and these moving objects react to swipe gestures and change their direction based on that. I am not using spritekit or any other gaming framework for this, and the way I am moving the objects is by triggering an NSTimer that fires 60 times a second. I am not using any threads explicitly so I guess the timer is executed by the main thread ? The code block that the timer triggers updates the location of objects based on their speed (defined as pixels per time unit in x/y direction). It is working fine and I am almost at the end of my project, but while testing the app I've realized that although the movement of objects seem pretty good most of the times, however sometimes the movement is a little rough/patchy.
My question is that is it the right way to do something like this, how can I improve the performance ? will using something like GCD can help with the issue of jittery movement ? (I haven't looked into GCD in detail but I am willing to spend time on it if I know that will help)

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Don't use `NSTimer`. Use `SpriteKit` and whatever scheduling they have, or if you want to use something else use `CADisplayLink`.

Comment: My first game was made on NSTimer with UIImageViews as sprites (Blast The Droids if u want to see it). It works okay as long as you don't use too many sprites. But since you said your game hit a performance issue, then I guess it is better to use SpriteKit. My 2nd, 3rd, 4th games all uses SpriteKit and I guarantee it is way better and not hard to learn either.

Comment: Thanks ! I am switching to SpriteKit now, seems pretty good so far :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and the way I am moving the objects is by triggering an NSTimer that fires 60 times a second

I would recommend not doing that. Various forms of animation are built in (View animation, Layer animation, CADisplayLink, UIKit Dynamics), and of course there's always Sprite Kit. Use the tools you are given for this purpose. Don't reinvent the unicycle when you already have a Ducati at your disposal.